# Closures captures value types

Tags: swift, closures

I ran code below, I was expecting that `print()`s would return zeroes as `i` and `s` a value types and would be copied into closure but appeared they were passed by reference. And for Objective-C, we have to use `__block` attribute to achieve such behaviour. Are there any explanations why it is so?

```
        var i = 0
        var s = "0"

        print(i)
        print(s)

        let c = {
            i = 1
            s = "11"
        }

        c()

        print(i)
        print(s)
```

the output is:

```
1
11
```

Comment: Swift's closures capture ("close over") all variables by ref. Copy captures simply aren't that useful. If you need copies of captured variables, you can just make the copies yourself

Answer (score 0):

Closures in Swift always capture variables by reference. It's equivalent to C/Objective-C blocks with all captured variables being `__block`.